# reading ip address ipv4 from keyboard and checking for its valid using scanf function

Tags: c++, c

i want to enter the ip address manually by keyboard using integers and dots 
the code should automatically check weather the  integers between the dots  ranges from o to 255

this was the sample code from the internet 
everything is perfect but i want a chance to enter ip address manually instead of using predefined ip addresses

```
  /* Sample code from Techpulp.
    * You are free to use this source code as you wish.
    * However Techpulp provides no warranty that this code works ans claims no       responsibility for any damage.
     * Author: neo@techpulp.com
     * http://www.techpulp.com/
    */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int is_valid_ip(const char *ip_str)
    {
unsigned int n1,n2,n3,n4;

if(sscanf(ip_str,"%u.%u.%u.%u", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4) != 4) return 0;

if((n1 != 0) && (n1 <= 255) && (n2 <= 255) && (n3 <= 255) && (n4 <= 255)) {
    char buf[64];
    sprintf(buf,"%u.%u.%u.%u",n1,n2,n3,n4);
    if(strcmp(buf,ip_str)) return 0;
    return 1;
}
return 0;
    }


    char *test_ips[] = {
"1.1.1.1",
"255.255.255.255",
"0.123.234.12",
"1.255.4.5",
"127.8.190.29",
"3hu23e832j2....wjdnw",
"3a.3b.2d.5t",
"-1.-1.-1.-1",
"1.1.1.1.3",
NULL
     };


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
int i = 0;

printf("\n------------------------------------------\n");
printf("IP Address Validation\n");
printf("------------------------------------------\n");
while(test_ips[i]) {
    printf("%20s\t%s\n",
        test_ips[i],
        is_valid_ip(test_ips[i])?"VALID ":"INVALID "
         );
    i++;
}
printf("------------------------------------------\n\n");

return 0;
    }
```

Comment: That isn't C#.  What have you tried?

Comment: For C, change sscanf to scanf to read from keyboard instead of string.

Answer (score 1):

Use scanf or fgets to read value from standard input/keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

E.g

```
int main(void){
    char input[32];

    printf("input IP Address : ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("%s\t%s\n",
      input,
      is_valid_ip(input)?"VALID ":"INVALID "
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace sscanf with scanf.

```
if(sscanf(ip_str,"%u.%u.%u.%u", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4) != 4) return 0;
```

will become

```
if(scanf(ip_str,"%u.%u.%u.%u", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4) != 4) return 0;
```

or use whatever function you like that takes from stdin.